# WD My Passport unusable after creating image with Clonezilla

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, backup, external-hard-drive, clonezilla

I have a WD My Passport with 1TB. I used Clonezilla-live device-image to create a backup of my whole hard drive. Note that I have done so once already but since it only backed up 2 partitions out of 5, I had to erase the WD drive through WD Drive Utilities or whatever it's called. After erasing and going through the whole process, I booted up Windows 10, opened up the drive and it looked like it backed up the whole disk this time, but my disk is far larger than 400GB (around 500GB) but Windows Explorer says only 400GB are used, so does WD Discovery. And the last failed backup also occupies EXACTLY 400GB. Even though Clonezilla can still read the image and restore from the drive and Windows can still detect it, I cannot copy files to it or anything. I'm looking to backup one of my other computers with EaseUS Todo PCTrans but when I choose the WD drive it says I cannot choose it. Tried setting read-write permissions, still happening. I really need help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to delete and then recreate the partition on the disk in Windows Disk Management? Also it's possible that the disk is write protected. How to undo that is explained in this acticle: https://www.easeus.com/storage-media-recovery/remove-write-protection-in-windows-10-8-7.html

Comment: I already made the disk read-write. Can copy files but it's still using 400GB and EaseUS Todo PCTrans still wouldn't let me save the image to the drive